# Using iPodMusicPlayer

Tags: ios4, xcode4, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller, avaudiosession

How to make my application to sing instead of the iPod when it's
 in the background. I think that I need to do my NSURL to MPMediaItem
 and play with iPodMusicPlayer. How can I do this?